# Liquibase Post Deployment Script in Oracle

Tags: deployment, liquibase

I am using .sql files for Liquibase changeset . In Pre deployment step , I am running few scripts like Disabled the Oracle jobs etc. When there is any error Liquibase Stop running next scripts.

In any case, I want run Post Deployment step scripts.

Is there any option in Liquibase for it ?

Run always sql scripts in case fail or success.

Answer (score 0):

Liquibase does not have any post deployment solution. I can see 2 ways:

1. You could write an extension to implement the post execution actions -> https://contribute.liquibase.com/extensions-integrations/extensions-overview/your-first-extension/
2. Liquibase stop processing when a changeset fails unless you set failOnError=false -> https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/attributes/fail-on-error.html . Adding this parameter to all changesets would make it run until the end - but you will need to review the logs for the errors as liquiabse will execute successfully.

Comment: > _Liquibase does not have any post deployment solution_ - it does, please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> In any case, I want run Post Deployment step scripts. Is there any option in Liquibase for it?

Yes, you can use [`runOrder`](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/attributes/run-order.html) changeset attribute:

> The `runOrder` attribute specifies whether a changeset should be run before or after all other changesets instead of running it sequentially based on its order in the changelog. Valid values are `first` and `last`. `runOrder` is not supported in formatted SQL changelogs.

To run a changeset in the end, set its `runOrder` to `last`. You might need to combine it with [`runAlways`](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/attributes/run-always.html). And you will have to change this changeset format to YAML, XML, or JSON.

> Run always sql scripts in case fail or success.

That would be a bit more complex. You can combine `runOrder` with [`preConditions`](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/preconditions.html), [`runAlways`](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/attributes/run-always.html), and [`failOnError`](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/attributes/fail-on-error.html). Also, remember to validate your [`rollback`](https://docs.liquibase.com/workflows/liquibase-community/using-rollback.html) statements.

Alternatively, you can use your deployment pipeline capabilities to run the post-deployment actions.